# How come my array index is faster than pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, indexing

Why the array index is faster than pointer?
Isn't pointer supposed to be faster than array index?

** i used time.h clock_t to tested two functions, each loop 2 million times.

```
Pointer time : 0.018995

Index time : 0.017864

void myPointer(int a[], int size)
{
     int *p;
     for(p = a; p < &a[size]; p++)
     {
         *p = 0;
     }
}


void myIndex(int a[], int size)
{
     int i;
     for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
     {
         a[i] = 0;
     }
}
```

Comment: I'd expect the pointer version to do `int * end = a + size;  for(p=a; a<end; p++)`

Comment: Those timings look awfully close, could easily be swayed by OS multithreading etc. Try running each of them 200 million times or even a billion times to reduce systemic error.

Comment: @missingno: gcc inserts that line of code at -O3.

Comment: Mildly relabeled,  and taken straight from "computer architecture and design"  (Patterson/henrssy). Your answer (other than below) is in the "elaboration" right below the example:..

Comment: The C is interesting, but the assembly is what will matter. In the VC 2008 examples below, the compiler renders the loop with REP STOSB, effectively using an assembly instruction (with arguments in registers) to pave over the memory. That is, the compiler is not doing literally what you asked for, so it does not make sense to ask how the two implementations differ.

Comment: If this is homework you should label it as such!

Comment: From real life experience in doing these timings, I suggest you switch the *order* of execution before relying on any kind of timing results. The first test you run generally goes a little bit slower. I believe this is due to the effects of cache warmup, but have not actually checked.

Comment: You should use the platform-specific functions to measure the time more accurately. On Windows for example `QueryPerformanceCounter`.

Answer (score 10):

No, never ever pointers are supposed to be faster than array index. If one of the code is faster than the other, it's mostly because some address computations might be different. The question also should provide information of compiler and optimization flags as it can heavily affect the performance.

Array index in your context (array bound is not known) is exactly identical to the pointer operation. From a viewpoint of compilers, it is just different expression of pointer arithmetic. Here is an example of an optimized x86 code in Visual Studio 2010 with *full optimization* and *no inline*.

```
     3: void myPointer(int a[], int size)
     4: {
013E1800  push        edi  
013E1801  mov         edi,ecx  
     5:      int *p;
     6:      for(p = a; p < &a[size]; p++)
013E1803  lea         ecx,[edi+eax*4]  
013E1806  cmp         edi,ecx  
013E1808  jae         myPointer+15h (13E1815h)  
013E180A  sub         ecx,edi  
013E180C  dec         ecx  
013E180D  shr         ecx,2  
013E1810  inc         ecx  
013E1811  xor         eax,eax  
013E1813  rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]  
013E1815  pop         edi  
     7:      {
     8:          *p = 0;
     9:      }
    10: }
013E1816  ret 

    13: void myIndex(int a[], int size)
    14: {
    15:      int i;
    16:      for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
013E17F0  test        ecx,ecx  
013E17F2  jle         myIndex+0Ch (13E17FCh)  
013E17F4  push        edi  
013E17F5  xor         eax,eax  
013E17F7  mov         edi,edx  
013E17F9  rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]  
013E17FB  pop         edi  
    17:      {
    18:          a[i] = 0;
    19:      }
    20: }
013E17FC  ret
```

At a glance, `myIndex` looks faster because the number of instructions are less, however, the two pieces of the code are essentially the same. Both eventually use `rep stos`, which is a x86's repeating (loop) instruction. The only difference is because of the computation of the loop bound. The `for` loop in `myIndex` has the trip count `size` as it is (i.e., no computation is needed). But, `myPointer` needs some computation to get the trip count of the `for` loop. This is the only difference. The important loop operations are just the same. Thus, the difference is negligible.

To summarize, the performance of `myPointer` and `myIndex` in an optimized code should be identical.

---

FYI, if the array's bound is known at compile time, e.g., `int A[constant_expression]`, then the accesses on this array may be much faster than the pointer one. This is mostly because the array accesses are free from the [pointer analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_analysis) problem. Compilers can perfectly compute the dependency information on computations and accesses on a fixed-size array, so it can do advanced optimizations including automatic parallelization.

However, if computations are pointer based, compilers must perform pointer analysis for further optimization, which is pretty much limited in C/C++. It generally ends up with conservative results on pointer analysis and results in a few optimization opportunity.

Comment: Would indices still be faster if you didn't use a for loop, but an array of indices (vs an array of pointers) instead? Something like this: arr[indices[i]]; vs pointers_to_arr[i];

Answer (score 5):

Array dereference `p[i]` is `*(p + i)`. Compilers make use of instructions that do math + dereference in 1 or 2 cycles (e.g. x86 LEA instruction) to optimize for speed.

With the pointer loop, it splits the access and offset into to separate parts and the compiler cannot optimize it.

Comment: Thanks! So in this case, pointer is always slower ? because compiler cannot optimize it.

Comment: I'm looking at the assembler output of gcc -O3 to see what the difference is when the only difference between the two is dereference-with-index vs plain-old-dereference.

Comment: I will say this: compiler optimization makes a far greater speed difference than indexed dereference vs plain dereference.

Comment: I'm doing timing loops with O0, O1, O2, O3 of the examples on an array of 1 million elements, repeated 1 million times. It will take me a few hours to get some numbers.

Comment: Wow..Thanks a lot, but you don't have to do that, it takes too much time. I did 2 million elements, repeated 1000 times and index beat the pointer.

Comment: Try it with the following modification in the pointer one: introduce a temporary variable `int *p_end = a + size`, then compare against `p_end` to isolate pointer vs index. My timings for 1000 runs of long[1000000] were as follows: gcc -O0 P: 4420000 I: 5460000; gcc -O1 P: 2260000 I: 2250000; gcc -O2 P: 2300000 I: 2290000; gcc -O3 P: 2280000 I: 2290000. Clearly, in the end, there's no real difference. Your overhead was in `&a[size]` computation.

Answer (score 5):

It may be the comparison in the for loop that is causing the difference. The termination condition is tested on each iteration, and your "pointer" example has a slightly more complicated termination condition (taking the address of &a[size]). Since &a[size] does not change, you could try setting it to a variable to avoid recalculating it on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Thanks! It did make pointer faster, but still a little bit slower than array index.

Comment: A compiling optimizer may make a register temporary whose value is `a + (size * (sizeof *a))`.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest running each loop 200 million times, and then run each loop 10 times, and take the fastest measurement. That will factor out effects from OS scheduling and so on.

I would then suggest you disassemble the code for each loop.

Answer (score 1):

Oops, on my 64-bit system results are quite different. I've got that this

```
 int i;

 for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
 {
     *(a+i) = 0;
 }
```

is about 100 times !! slower than this

```
 int i;
 int * p = a;

 for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
 {
     *(p++) = 0;
 }
```

when compiling with `-O3`.  This hints to me that somehow moving to next address is far easier to achieve for 64-bit cpu, than to calculate destination address from some offset. But i'm not sure.

**EDIT:** 
This really has something related with 64-bit architecture because same code with same compile flags doesn't shows any real difference in performance on 32-bit system.

Comment: Probably in the second case, the compiler has recognized the pattern and parallelized the loop with SSE/MMX instructions. Such instructions are always available on 64-bit architectures, whereas on 32-bit the compiler can't assume their availability (unless you provide some explicit hints at compile time).

Comment: Your code is obviously wrong if the difference is 100 times. The slowest part is the memory access, and that is the same no matter what the loop does. (Did you do one, followed by the other perhaps?) I'd compare with std::fill to see which one is the "odd one"

Answer (score 1):

**Compiler optimizations are pattern matching.**

When your compiler optimizes, it looks for known code patterns, and then transforms the code according to some rule. Your two code snippets seem to trigger different transforms, and thus produce slightly different code.

This is one of the reasons why we always insist to actually measure the resulting performance when it comes to optimizations: You can never be sure what your compiler turns your code into unless you test it.

---

If you are really curious, try compiling your code with `gcc -S -Os`, this produces the most readable, yet optimized assembler code. On your two functions, I get the following assembler with that:

```
pointer code:
.L2:
    cmpq    %rax, %rdi
    jnb .L5
    movl    $0, (%rdi)
    addq    $4, %rdi
    jmp .L2
.L5:

index code:
.L7:
    cmpl    %eax, %esi
    jle .L9
    movl    $0, (%rdi,%rax,4)
    incq    %rax
    jmp .L7
.L9:
```

The differences are slight, but may indeed trigger a performance difference, most importantly the difference between using `addq` and `incq` could be significant.

Answer (score 0):

The times are so close together that if you did them repeatedly, you may not see much of a difference. Both code segments compile to the *exact* same assembly. By definition, there is no difference.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the index solution can save a few instructions with the compare in the for loop.

Comment: Is this a Debug build? The output for a Release build with optimization is dramatically different.

Comment: Yeah I just realized that it forgot to grab the release file... @minjang already posted the same assembly, so I'l just remove the debug build

Answer (score 0):

Access the data through array index or pointer is exactly equivalent. Go through the below program with me...

There are a loop which continues to 100 times but when we see disassemble code that there are the data which we access through has least instruction comparability to access through array Index

But it doesn't mean that accessing data through pointer is fast actually it's depend on the instruction which performed by compiler.Both the pointer and array index used the address array access the value from offset and increment through it and pointer has address.

```
int a[100];
fun1(a,100);
fun2(&a[0],5);
}
void fun1(int a[],int n)
{
int i;
for(i=0;i<=99;i++)
{
a[i]=0;
printf("%d\n",a[i]);
}
}
void fun2(int *p,int n)
{
int i;
for(i=0;i<=99;i++)
{
*p=0;
printf("%d\n",*(p+i));
}
}


disass fun1
Dump of assembler code for function fun1:
   0x0804841a <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x0804841b <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x0804841d <+3>: sub    $0x28,%esp`enter code here`
   0x08048420 <+6>: movl   $0x0,-0xc(%ebp)
   0x08048427 <+13>:    jmp    0x8048458 <fun1+62>
   0x08048429 <+15>:    mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
   0x0804842c <+18>:    shl    $0x2,%eax
   0x0804842f <+21>:    add    0x8(%ebp),%eax
   0x08048432 <+24>:    movl   $0x0,(%eax)
   0x08048438 <+30>:    mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
   0x0804843b <+33>:    shl    $0x2,%eax
   0x0804843e <+36>:    add    0x8(%ebp),%eax
   0x08048441 <+39>:    mov    (%eax),%edx
   0x08048443 <+41>:    mov    $0x8048570,%eax
   0x08048448 <+46>:    mov    %edx,0x4(%esp)
   0x0804844c <+50>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x0804844f <+53>:    call   0x8048300 <printf@plt>
   0x08048454 <+58>:    addl   $0x1,-0xc(%ebp)
   0x08048458 <+62>:    cmpl   $0x63,-0xc(%ebp)
   0x0804845c <+66>:    jle    0x8048429 <fun1+15>
   0x0804845e <+68>:    leave  
   0x0804845f <+69>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) disass fun2
Dump of assembler code for function fun2:
   0x08048460 <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x08048461 <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x08048463 <+3>: sub    $0x28,%esp
   0x08048466 <+6>: movl   $0x0,-0xc(%ebp)
   0x0804846d <+13>:    jmp    0x8048498 <fun2+56>
   0x0804846f <+15>:    mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
   0x08048472 <+18>:    movl   $0x0,(%eax)
   0x08048478 <+24>:    mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
   0x0804847b <+27>:    shl    $0x2,%eax
   0x0804847e <+30>:    add    0x8(%ebp),%eax
   0x08048481 <+33>:    mov    (%eax),%edx
   0x08048483 <+35>:    mov    $0x8048570,%eax
   0x08048488 <+40>:    mov    %edx,0x4(%esp)
   0x0804848c <+44>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x0804848f <+47>:    call   0x8048300 <printf@plt>
   0x08048494 <+52>:    addl   $0x1,-0xc(%ebp)
   0x08048498 <+56>:    cmpl   $0x63,-0xc(%ebp)
   0x0804849c <+60>:    jle    0x804846f <fun2+15>
   0x0804849e <+62>:    leave  
   0x0804849f <+63>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
(gdb)
```

Comment: Your example is flawed. The compiler can see the size of the loop, and understands what it is doing, which is why both examples are the same. If your loop was small enough, the compiler might even remove the loop entirely (google loop unrolling). To test for speed you need to hide the size (as the original question does)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very hard thing to time, because compilers are very good at optimising these things. Still it's better to give the compiler as much information as possible, that's why in this case I'd advise using std::fill, and let the compiler choose.

But... If you want to get into the detail

a) CPU's normally give pointer+value for free, like : mov r1, r2(r3).
b) This means an index operation requires just :  mul r3,r1,size
   This is just one cycle extra, per loop.
c) CPU's often provide stall/delay slots, meaning you can often hide single-cycle operations.

All in all, even if your loops are very large, the cost of the access is nothing compared to the cost of even a few cache-misses. You are best advised to optimise your structures before you care about loop costs. Try for example, [packing your structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) to reduce the memory footprint first